# how to add a new field to an array of structures in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have a large array of structures with fields `A(1:10000).image`, `A(1:10000).size`, ...

I need to add a new field, let's say `A.number`. I need to see `A.image` in order to assign the new field value `A.number` (an integer value).

This is a pseudo-code of what I need:

```
for k=1:10000
    imshow(A(k).image)
    enter a number with the keyboard that is assigned to A(k).number
    load next image
end
```

I guess a GUI/script is the best. Any code to do this in a fast way?

Answer (score 0):

how about [`input`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html)?

```
for k=1:10000
    imshow(A(k).image)
    A(k).number = input('enter value');
end
```